# How do i check if all keys in an array have empty values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$array = array('key1' => null, 'key2' => null, 'key3' => null, 'key4' => null);
```

i would like to determine if all the array keys have empty values if so then return false. the above example should return false as it does not have any value. but if one or more keys have any values then it should return true for example the below example is true.

```
$array = array('value1', 'key2' => value2, 'value3', 'key4' => value4);
```

Comment: All the keys do have values, the keys just aren't what you think they are. `Array
(
    [0] => key1
    [1] => key2
    [2] => key3
    [3] => key4
)` and `Array
(
    [0] => key1
    [key2] => value2
    [1] => key3
    [key4] => value4
)` respectively.

Comment: sorry, i knew that, and i was missing the point :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Assuming you actually mean an array like

```
array('key1' => null, 'key2' => null, 'key3' => null, 'key4' => null)
```

the answer is simply using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
if (!array_filter($array)) {
    // all values are empty (where "empty" means == false)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption is incorrect. `array('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4')` has 4 values and keys in the range `0..3`.

`array('key1', 'key2' => value2, 'key3', 'key4' => value4)` has the value `key1` (with key 0), the key `key2`, the value `key3` (with key 1) and the key `key4`.

Comment: @Ibrahim: try `print_r($array)` then you should see how you array looks like. blagovest is completly right.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check if all values are `null`

```
$allNull = true;
foreach( $array as $key => $val ) {
    if( is_null( $array[$key] ) ) {
        $allNull = false;
        break;
    }
}

// Do what you will with $allNull
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('key1' => null, 'key2' => null, 'key3' => null, 'key4' => null);
```

The answer is

```
$filterArray = array_filter($array);

if(count($filterArray) == 0){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```