# codeigniter validation should work only when array of email id is not empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, email

I am doing codeigniter validation for email id. I have declared 3 text box for entering email id. I am retrieving all the 3 email id's in array called ref_email. now I want to do email id validation only when email id text boxes are not empty and show error message in view page. if email id text boxes are empty, then i don't want to do any validation. I don't know where i have done mistake in my code.

My controller code:

```
    $ref_email_array=$this->input->post('ref_email');

            foreach($ref_email_array as $key => $r_email ){
        if ($r_email!="") {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('ref_email['.$key.']', 'Email','trim|valid_email');
                $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error_user" style="color:red">', '</div>');
                }
            }
           if($this->form_validation->run()){   // insertion code }
```

can anybody help me?
thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use php `empty()` function to check whether input array is empty or not?

Comment: I just want to check only when array value is not empty.. I am using 3 text boxes so my array always return 0,1,2 index, so array wont be empty.

Comment: Use array_filter to check if all keys have value or not. [Check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339704/how-do-i-check-if-all-keys-in-an-array-have-empty-values-in-php)

Comment: okay i will try and let you know. there is no use of using array filter

Answer (score 0):

```
$ref_email_array=$this->input->post('ref_email');
foreach($ref_email_array as $r_email ){
if (empty($r_email)) {}
else  {
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ref_email['.$key.']','Email','trim|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error_user" style="color:red">', '</div>');
      }
 }
```

I hope this might help you ! , it works for me